# Prove that $A ⊆ f^{−1}(f(A))$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets, $f:X→Y$ a function, $A⊆X$ and $B⊆Y$.

Prove that $A ⊆ f^{−1}(f(A))$.

I am confused on how to start this, as previously I showed that $f(f^{-1}(B))⊆ B$, so I not sure why $A$ is now the subset while $B$ was the set.

Comment: Start with the definition of the inverse image.

Comment: You can easily prove both parts of your exercise by first proving $f(A) \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow A \subseteq f^{-1}(B)$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $f^{(-1)}(f(A)) = \{ x \in X \mid f(x) \in f(A) \}$ and that $f(A) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in A \}$.

If $x \in A$, then $f(x) \in f(A)$ by definition and then $x \in f^{(-1)}(f(A))$.

Comment: @Nex Yes, sure; thank you for detecting the typo :)